# (python) transfering data variable to live running file

Tags: python, data-transfer

I host a game server/console on my desktop and
I have a python program that chooses a random weapon for a game (unturned). it is fully automatic except for one thing. A variable is compiled at the end of the program. that variable must be pasted to the game server / console. I looked well, but I could not find any solution. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I'm a bit new
thanks!

Comment: You should use a database.

Comment: You should be able to pipe the standard output of your program (i.e. the result of `print` statements) to the input of the server program writing something like `python myProgram.py | serverProgram` in your terminal. However that requires that `myProgram.py` generates _all_ the input that the server program needs.

Comment: dear jdehesa, I compiled the myProgram.py output like: give [playername]/[randomgun]. the ServerProgram is like a batchfile and the command needs to be only copied from the shell to the batchfile while running. do you know a module or a way that copies one variable and pasts it in the server console. here is a picture of the server console: https://www.google.nl/search?q=unturned+server&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY2snSocHYAhUNDuwKHXsVAvMQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=940#imgrc=t157-RmP7Ws5QM: sorry for my bad inglish